# Connect library created with Julia's PackageCompiler demo to a c# program

Tags: c#, .net, julia, packagecompiler.jl

Programs written in the Julia language can be compiled with the help of the package PackageCompiler.jl to a library that facilitates linking and use by external (non-Julian) programs. In the [help pages of PackageCompiler.jl](https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/libs.html) is a very simple demonstration about how to export two increment methods for variables of type integer and long.

After compiling this demonstration library a libinc.dll library file is created containing the increment methods, together with 53 dll files and one executable.
First I tried copying all 55 files to the same folder as the .net executable. (The bin/debug/.net7.0-windows folder.) I got the error:

> Unable to load dependent library
> myfolder\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows../bin/libopenlibm.dll

So I copied all library files except libinc.dll to a bin folder below the folder with the .net executable. Now I get the error:

> Unable to load DLL 'libinc.dll' or one of its dependencies: The
> specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E)

I can't see what dll file is missing.
So for the program to work I must have the 54 dll files in two places: A separate bin folder and the program folder.

How can I have a .net program that uses only one copy of the julia library? And preferably not a bin folder below the program folder?

Here's the console program:

```
// See https://aka.ms/new-console-template for more information
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


Wrapper.init_julia(0, new string[1] { "" });
int start = 1;
int ret = Wrapper.increment32(start);
Console.WriteLine($"When you add 1 to {start} you get: {ret}.");
Console.ReadKey();
Wrapper.shutdown_julia(0);

public static class Wrapper
{
    [DllImport("libinc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern void init_julia(int argc, string[] argv);

    [DllImport("libinc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern void shutdown_julia(int retcode);

    [DllImport("libinc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern int increment32(int value);

    [DllImport("libinc.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern long increment64(long value);
}
```

Here's The project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl/issues/658) on Github that had a solution for my problem. The solution removes the lines that have "../bin/" in the generated libjulia.dll file. It's not the most elegant solution but it works for now. Below you see how I've changed the [build.jl file](https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl/tree/master/examples/MyLib/build) of the example project.

```
using PackageCompiler

target_dir = get(ENV, "OUTDIR", "$(@__DIR__)/../../MyLibCompiled")
target_dir = replace(target_dir, "\\" => "/")       # Change Windows paths to use "/"

println("Creating library in $target_dir")
PackageCompiler.create_library(".", target_dir;
    lib_name="libinc",
    precompile_execution_file=["$(@__DIR__)/generate_precompile.jl"],
    precompile_statements_file=["$(@__DIR__)/additional_precompile.jl"],
    incremental=false,
    filter_stdlibs=true,
    header_files=["$(@__DIR__)/mylib.h"]
)

libjulia_path = joinpath(target_dir,"bin/libjulia.dll")
libjulia_path = replace(libjulia_path, "\\" => "/")       # Change Windows paths to use "/"

if !isfile(libjulia_path)
    error("Unable to open libjulia.dll at $(libjulia_path)")
end

open(libjulia_path, read=true, write=true) do io
    # Search for ../bin/ string:
    needle = "../bin/"
    readuntil(io, needle)
    skip(io, -length(needle))
    libpath_offset = position(io)

    libpath = split(String(readuntil(io, UInt8(0))), ":")
    @info("Found embedded libpath", libpath, libpath_offset)

    # Get rid of `../bin/` prefix:
    libpath = map(libpath) do l
        if startswith(l, "../bin/")
            return l[8:end]
        end
        if startswith(l, "@../bin/")
            return "@" * l[9:end]
        end
    end

    @info("Filtered libpath", libpath)

    # Write filtered libpath out to the file, terminate with NULL.
    seek(io, libpath_offset)
    libspath = join(libpath, ":")
    Base.write(io, libspath)
    Base.write(io, UInt8(0))
end
```